# How to use an earlier Task's output in Luigi?

Tags: python, luigi

I'm writing a pipeline in which later tasks need to read the output of earlier tasks, so they can know what parameters they need to pass in their requirements.

I've created a simplified example of my setup below.

```
import random
import pickle
import luigi


class WriteNumbers(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # pickle a random list of ints 1-100
        numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
        pickle.dump(numbers, open("./numbers.pkl", 'wb'))

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("./numbers.pkl")


class SquareNumber(luigi.Task):
    number = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # given a number as the parameter, write a file containing its square
        with open("./squared_{}".format(self.number), 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(self.number ** 2))

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("./squared_{}".format(self.number))


class SquareAll(luigi.WrapperTask):

    def requires(self):
        yield WriteNumbers()  # require the number list to be pickled first
        numbers = pickle.load("./numbers.pkl")  # load the number list
        for n in numbers:  # square each number in the number list
            yield SquareNumber(number=n)

class CubeNumber(luigi.Task):
    number = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # given a number as the parameter, write a file containing its cube
        with open("./cubed_{}".format(self.number), 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(self.number ** 3))

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("./cubed_{}".format(self.number))


class CubeAll(luigi.WrapperTask):

    def requires(self):
        yield WriteNumbers()  # require the number list to be pickled first
        numbers = pickle.load("./numbers.pkl")  # load the number list
        for n in numbers:  # square each number in the number list
            yield CubeNumber(number=n)

class CrunchNumbers(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        yield SquareAll()
        yield CubeAll()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

When run via `python luigi_example.py CrunchNumbers`, 100 random numbers will be created and the list pickled & dumped to disk.  `SquareAll` loads that pickled list and uses it to require the `SquareNumber` tasks with the needed parameters.  `CubeAll` references the same result file for its similar task.

The problem being, when run an exception will be thrown because the `numbers.pkl` file does not yet exist.

How can I allow later tasks to generate dependencies based on the output of an earlier task?  I have used random numbers here to indicate that the output cannot be known ahead of time: my actual application is crunching data from an API.

Comment: I think you should try looking up in the `luigi` documentation to see if any communication between task, any way of returning data or objects, is implemented since using files for this is not exactly the best way.

Comment: Does CubeNumber/SquareNumber actually need to be a task? Why not just have CubeNumbers and SquareNumbers be tasks with run methods?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Dynamic Dependencies](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#dynamic-dependencies) and these need to be called from the `run` method (when the results of the `requires` are available as `input`), so `CubeAll` and `SquareAll` should be structured like this:

```
class SquareAll(luigi.WrapperTask):

    def requires(self):
        yield WriteNumbers()  # require the number list to be pickled first

    def run(self):
        numbers_file = self.input()[0].path
        numbers = pickle.load(numbers_file)  # load the number list
        for n in numbers:  # square each number in the number list
            yield SquareNumber(number=n)
```